# javascrpit - if-statement doesn't work. doesn't align number to variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hello people of stackoverflow,

I am having a problem, where the console doens't print out "geschafft", like i wanted it to. 
I wanted to build an Website, wehere it counts, how fast you typed numbers so i need to check if the number typed by the user equals the given number. The Code snipped that doesn't work is:

```
var gedrueckt = "";
var zahl = "";
var spielerZahl = '';
//erzeugen der Zufallszahl
var min = 0;
var max = 9;
var zahl = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
console.log(zahl);
//Zahl in HTML ausgeben
document.getElementById("zutippen").innerHTML = zahl;

//Erkennung der Taste
window.addEventListener("keydown", TasteGedrueckt,);
function TasteGedrueckt (evt) {
     gedrueckt = evt.key;
        if (gedrueckt == 1){
            spielerZahl = 1;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 2){
            spielerZahl = 2;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 3){
            spielerZahl = 3;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 4){
            spielerZahl = 4;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 5){
            spielerZahl = 5;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 6){
            spielerZahl = 6;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 7){
            spielerZahl = 7;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 8){
            spielerZahl = 8;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 9){
            spielerZahl = 9;
        }
        else if (gedrueckt == 0){
            spielerZahl = 0;
        }
        console.log(spielerZahl);
}

//Überprüfung ob zahl gleich
if (zahl == spielerZahl){
    console.log("geschafft!");
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, I hope someone can help my. Googled for three days, also tried parseInt and nothing seems to work..

Comment: That `if` block at the end runs when the page is loaded, then never again. If you want to run it after a keypress, you have to move it inside the event handler function. Also, that bunch of `else if`s is extremely redundant; you can just check `evt.key` for being inside the allowed range, then directly call `spielerZahl = evt.key;`

Comment: thank you guys you are awsome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the checking after the use presses a key, so the check must be called by the event listener.
Also you can check if the key is the same by doing `+evt.key === zahl` or `evt.key == zahl`.

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 9;
var zahl = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
console.log(zahl);
document.getElementById("zutippen").innerHTML = zahl;
window.addEventListener("keydown", TasteGedrueckt);

function TasteGedrueckt(evt) {
  if (+evt.key === zahl) {
    console.log("geschafft!");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="zutippen"></div>
```

I assume you will eventually want to get it working for more than 1 item, in which case you could do:

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 9;
var zahl;
window.addEventListener("keydown", TasteGedrueckt);
nextNumber();

function TasteGedrueckt(evt) {
  if (+evt.key === zahl) {
    console.log("geschafft!");
    nextNumber();
  }
}

function nextNumber() {
  zahl = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  console.log(zahl);
  document.getElementById("zutippen").innerHTML = zahl;
}
```

```html
<div id="zutippen"></div>
```

Comment: and if I put the nextNumber function inside the TasteGerueckt function i only need the button for starting off right?
like this:
function TasteGedrueckt(evt) {
  if (zahl === undefined) return;
  if (+evt.key === zahl) {
    console.log("geschafft!");
    zahl = undefined;
 nextNumber();
  }
}

Comment: @NetiHeft Yes, you could put inside the `if` block if you want to get a new number only when the use presses the right key, or at the bottom of the function, to refresh the number after every attempt(right or wrong) (Edited the answer)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var gedrueckt = "";
var spielerZahl = '';
//erzeugen der Zufallszahl
var min = 0;
var max = 9;
var zahl = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;


function TasteGedrueckt (evt) {
  console.log('spielerZahl: ' + evt.key);
  //Überprüfung ob zahl gleich
  if(evt.key == zahl) {
    console.log("geschafft!");
  }   
}

//Zahl in HTML ausgeben
document.getElementById("zutippen").innerHTML = 'Gesuchte Zahl: ' + zahl;
window.addEventListener("keydown", TasteGedrueckt);
```

```html
<div id="zutippen"></div>
```